# I keep getting undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var eaclink = $('a.topLink'),
eacwrap = $('div.pan_inner');

for(var i = 0; i < eaclink.length; i++) {
    eacwrap[i].wrap('<div class="panel panel-default"><div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in"><div class="panel-body"></div></div></div>');
    eaclink[i].attr("data-toggle", "collapse").attr("data-parent", "#accordion").attr("href", "collapse1");
}
```

How do I know whats the undefined function?

Comment: What line has the error?

Comment: The developer console will show you a line number along with the error. It could be as simple as a failure to import jQuery (which would cause the first call to `$()` to give the error).

Comment: Or, (if jQuery is included correctly), because the code is executing before jQuery was properly loaded. You should wrap your code in a closure in that case (eg. `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { /* your code here */ } );`

Comment: `eacwrap[i].wrap` is wrong syntax. `eacwrap[i]` is DOM element which has no `wrap` method. You have to use `eq` method: `eacwrap.eq(i).wrap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `wrap` and `attr` will be not a function because you're operating on a DOM element instead of a jQuery object.

Use `.eq(i)` instead of `[i]` to fetch the element wrapped with a jQuery object.

Example:

```
eacwrap.eq(1).wrap()
```

Comment: ... or `$(eacwrap[i]).attr(...)`.