# Get text from all elements within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div (example taken from https://api.jquery.com/contents/):

```
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <br><br>
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  <br><br>
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</div>
```

And then I try to get all the text from div, format it with `<p>` tags and strip `br` tags:

```
  TextVar = 
  $( ".container" )
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
     return this.nodeType === 3;
   })
  .wrap( "<p></p>" )
  .end()
  .filter( "br" )
  .remove();
```

But I then get an error `undefined is not a function`. I then drop `.wrap("<p></p>")` to test (see this answer for example [I keep getting undefined is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217774/i-keep-getting-undefined-is-not-a-function)). But if I drop `wrap`, the code does not throw an error, but instead I only get `<br><br><br><br>`. How should I change my code to get the text?

Comment: So your goal is to wrap the text separated by `<br><br>` in paragraph tags and remove the `<br><br>`? Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nuw8quc8/. Did you include jQuery and run your jQuery code after the div was created?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var _html = "<p>" + $(".container").text() + "</p>";
```

Comment: How does this wrap the text in the div which is currently separated by divs with paragraph elements?

Comment: Currently seprated by what divs? Their is just one div, i am fetching its `text` which automatically removes `<br>` and then i am wrapping it in `p` .. i dont see any issue?

Comment: That's a typo. Separated by `<br><br>`. The OP wants the text that's separated by the breaks to each be wrapped in paragraphs.

Comment: What do you mean by `That's a typo. Separated by <br><br>.`?

Comment: Yeah so `.text()` will remove the `br`, whats wrong?

Comment: He doesn't just want to remove the `<br>` elements in the div. He wants to use them as separators and wrap each group of text in paragraph tags. The bigger issue is that the OP's code works fine as my fiddle shows.

Comment: @void But how to get line breaks as in div?

Comment: What do you mean by `how to get line breaks as in div?`? Please trying explain it once..

Comment: @void I want only the text (no html stuff :)) breaked in lines just as in div. Is it possible?:)

Comment: so you want line breaks without `br`?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! Possible or not? :)

Comment: @void Your example works very good anyway, but linebreaks without br would be great if possible

Comment: Will you use this string in something non html? Because `<br>` is the only way in html to put line breaks.. If you gonna use it in something else the you  have `\n`

Comment: @void Yes. I simply want to keep linebreaking but without html. Please tell me if you have any solution for this:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95050/discussion-between-void-and-user1665355).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is like this:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z0wL5ckt/

```
var text = $(".container").text();
var paragraph = $("<p>" + text + "</p>");
$('body').append(paragraph);
```

Update to split text into paragraphs based on `<br><br>`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z0wL5ckt/4/

```
var text = $(".container").html();
var textSplit = text.split('<br><br>');
var paragraphs = '', index = 0, length = textSplit.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    paragraphs += "<p>" + textSplit[index] + "</p>";
}
$('body').append(paragraphs);
```

EDIT: Bonus pure javascript solution if interested! =]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z0wL5ckt/3/

```
var text = document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML;
var textSplit = text.split('<br>');
var paragraphs = '', index = 0, length = textSplit.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    paragraphs += "<p>" + textSplit[index] + "</p>";
}
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += paragraphs;
```

UPDATE: For pure text use this

```
var text = $(".container").text();
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/

UPDATE: Here is just the text with it still breaking lines but this will not work for display in HTML but it will keep the lines broken for display else where.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z0wL5ckt/5/

```
var text = $(".container").html();
var textSplit = text.split('<br><br>');
var textWithBreaks = '';
var paragraphs = '', index = 0, length = textSplit.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    paragraphs += "<p>" + textSplit[index] + "</p>";
    textWithBreaks += textSplit[index] + '\n';
}
$('body').append(paragraphs);
```

Comment: Ok, but I want to save to a variable. Where each br row is formatted with p tag

Comment: @user1665355 - Your current code works fine; see the fiddle in my comment.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace great answers. But how can I only get text, and strip all html attributes and stuff? :)

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I mean. I want to keep linebreaking as in div. Else the words are concantened without linebreaks:/

Comment: @user1665355 So you want all the text inside the .container div including the `<br>` line breaks?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I want only the text (no html stuff :)) breaked in lines just as in div. Is it possible?:)

Comment: @AtheistP3ace " For pure text use this", works in all 3 examples?

Comment: It won't work to split them on `<br>` since the text function removes all html and leaves only pure text.

Comment: `var text = $(".container").html();
var textSplit = text.split('<br><br>');` These lines will get all the HTML inside .container div and create an array where each index is a section of all the text previously broken apart by line breaks. Then you can do what every you want with that data.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Ok i see. But if only keep `<br>` but no other html stuff?

Comment: It seems like the scope of your question is constantly changing. I am starting to become confused on what you are looking for as the final outcome. Do you want each section of text in its own paragraph? Do you want just the text? Do you want the text still broken by line breaks. If so do you want a single line break or the double that currently exists?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Sorry... But if I get html I see very strange characters in text. Not what I want:/ I simply want to keep linebreaks without html. :) Without linebreaks, the last word and the first word on next line become one word:/

Comment: I updated answer to add a variable that has text with end of line characters but that won't work to display in HTML.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Hm, with the last solution I get those stuff `M&#xE4`, `&#xE4` and so on.. No pure text: /

Comment: Where are you seeing that? How are you trying to display this data?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I output it to mongodb.